# Input checkbox not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

My checkbox isn't displaying in Chrome. It displays in other projects, but not in this one. I tried adding `input[type="checkbox"] {-webkit-appearance: checkbox;}` to my CSS, but that didn't work either. I'm not sure what else to do.

My code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-8">
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="playerLeaderStats" value="goals" />Goals
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="playerLeaderStats" value="redCards" />Red Cards
      <br />
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is happening?

Comment: Can you share with us your css code? (I can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eoxoqxcj/3/), perhaps something is wrong with your css)

Comment: Provide the CSS code

Comment: You should not have 2 checkboxes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code where the checkbox does not working ?

It working on Chrome, Firefox, IE : [result on Chrome v54](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXbHE.png)

Did you see if you've forgot a css property who modifying this type of input ?
Look with the **Page Inspector** if your input is really where it supposed to be even if it not visible ?